# Searching array of objects not returning desired result

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects

I am working on a project of mine where I have this contact list `contacts` which is an `array` containing `objects`.

The problem is that my function `searchPerson` always returns the response for the condition of the searched for person not existing. 
As soon as I remove the condition and call the function again it returns what was searched for.

I don't understand why with the condition it always return `no such person found!` when that person exists in the contact list! Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

This is my code.

```
var bob = {
firstName: "Bob",
lastName: "Jones",
phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

//Here we populate ou array.
var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}


function searchPerson (lastName) {
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++){
      //set a condition that we only retrieve the last name if it already exists in out contact list
        if(lastName !== contacts[i].lastName){
            return console.log("No such person found!");
        } else {
            printPerson(contacts[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RobG IMHO, JS would be a better language without the coercing `==` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're enumerating the entire array, but return "No such person found" as soon as *any* non-matching person is found.  Since the two last names are not the same, you'll *always* trigger that `return` line.

Consider using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead to find matching entries:

```
function searchPerson(lastName) {
    var matches = contacts.filter(function(contact) {
        return contact.lastName === lastName;
    });

    if (matches.length) {
        matches.forEach(printPerson);
    } else {
        console.log("No such person found!");
    }
}
```

NB: `.filter` and `.forEach` are ES5 functions (IE9+ only AFAICR).  Use a ["shim"](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) to add them to your browser if required.

Comment: `filter` is not short-circuiting however, so it's not very efficient, but it shouldn't matter for a few records.

Comment: @plalx indeed - I considered that - a mere existence test would be faster with `Array.prototype.any`, but that doesn't also print the match, it just proves its existence.  You _could_ put the call to `printPerson` inside the `.any` function's callback, but that's slightly messy.  In any event, the OP's code _appears_ intended to print every match, so short circuiting wouldn't be required.

Comment: @plalx yes - `.some`, not `.any` !  (too many languages in my head!)

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks! I understand now! Once you explained the problem I simply replaced `console.log("No such person found");` with `continue;` and it worked too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the logic so that for each match found, print the name. If no matches are found, return an error.

```
function searchPerson (lastName) {
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;

    // Remember if a match is found
    var matchFound = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {

        // Print each match
        if (lastName == contacts[i].lastName) {
            printPerson(contacts[i]);
            matchFound = true;
        }
    }

    // If no match found, return error message
    if (!matchFound) {
        console.log('Person ' + lastName + ' not found!');
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alnitak—you're welcome to that opinion. To me, the plain JS solution is simpler and [hugely faster](http://jsperf.com/es5-vs-pojs)—about 10 times—and doesn't require shims or special consideration for any browser in use.

Comment: ES5 _is_ plain JS!  You're correct though that the function call overhead can be a little high.  It would be interesting to see how that changes with a much larger array.